# Favorite Question and Answers from Fourth Quarter 2020

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

[Blog Post](https://thesffblog.com/2021/02/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-fourth-quater-2020/)

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2020 through December 31st 2020.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/10/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/10/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/10/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.